# What happens when we theta join or cross 2 relations with common attributes?

Tags: relational-database, relational-algebra

```
Relation 1 (r1):
ID | Name
1    John
2    Doe
3    Foo  

Relation 2 (r2):
ID | Name
4    Johnny
5    Doey
6    Fooey
```

What will `r1 theta join(r1.ID = r2.ID) r2` result in?

What will `r1 cross r2` result in?

I'm just asking whether the resulting relations should change the names of the attributes to something else because there are 2 of each.

Answer (score 1):

In relational algebra, product (cross join) is usually understood to be a special case of natural join where the joined relations happen to have no attributes in common. So it doesn't make sense to say A x B if A and B have common attributes. If A and B have attributes in common then A x B either means A ⋈ B or it means a mistake has been made and your DBMS or interpreter probably ought to report an error.

Theta join is a shorthand for natural join followed by a restriction. It must be preceded by a rename of some attribute(s) if the attributes in the theta expression would otherwise have the same names.